# Round to the nearest 0.5 decimal in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to round a variable to the nearest 0.5 decimal in bash.

For instance, 1.3 should be 1.5, 1.15 should be 1, 2.8 should be 3, etc...

Comment: Unfortunately that example doesn't round to the nearest multiple of 0.5...

Comment: You should probably show what have you tried so far in order to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a simpler way to do this but this should work:

```
echo "1.3 * 2" | bc | xargs -I{ printf "%1.f" { | xargs -I% echo "% * .5" | bc
#1.5

echo "1.15 * 2" | bc | xargs -I{ printf "%1.f" { | xargs -I% echo "% * .5" | bc
#1.0

echo "2.8 * 2" | bc | xargs -I{ printf "%1.f" { | xargs -I% echo "% * .5" | bc
#3.0
```

So the only thing you're changing here is the first number of the echo value. If you want a function...

```
function roundhalves { echo "$1 * 2" | bc | xargs -I@ printf "%1.f" @ | xargs -I% echo "% * .5" | bc }
```

And just call it like this:

```
roundhalves 1.3
roundhalves 1.15
roundhalves 2.8
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Why all that mucking with xargs? `roundhalves() { local val; val=$(bc <<<"$1 * 2"); printf -v val '%1.f' "$val"; bc <<<"$val * .5"; }`

Comment: No problemo. @CharlesDuffy nice one!

Comment: ...or, perhaps clearer (though a little less efficient at runtime): `roundhalves() { bc <<<"$(printf %1.f "$(bc <<<"$1 * 2")" ) * 0.5"; }`

Comment: Feel free to edit to adopt any of my suggestions if you feel so inclined.

Comment: Charles, that actually works great too. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Bash only (no call to `bc` or other external calculator), with support for all kinds of decimal numbers with or without sign, with or without integer part and with or without fractional part:

```
function roundhalves () {
    [[ $1 =~ ^([\+-]?)([0-9]*)\.([0-9]+)$ ]] || { printf "%s\n" "$1" && return; }
    s=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    a=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    (( b = 1${BASH_REMATCH[3]} * 2 ))
    [[ $b =~ ^([0-9][0-9])[0-9]*$ ]] && b=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    (( b < 25 ? (b = 0) : b >= 35 ? (a += 1, b = 0) : (b = 5) ))
    printf "%s%s.%d\n" "$s" "$a" "$b"
}
```

Note: the algorithm is simple: take the fractional part, prepend a 1, multiply by 2 and keep the two leading (leftmost) digits. The resulting integer is in the `[20..39]` range. Compare with 25 and 35.

Note: the rounding is towards infinity but this is easy to modify.

Note: this is limited by the maximum representable numbers (`[-2**63..2**63-1]` on 64 bits architectures). There is not such limitation with `bc`. If your numbers may have a lot (more than 18) of digits either in the integer or fractional parts, and if you have it, prefer `bc`.

Demo:

```bash
$ roundhalves 1.3
1.5
$ roundhalves 1.15
1.0
$ roundhalves 2.8
3
$ roundhalves 1.7499999
1.5
$ roundhalves 1.7500000
2.0
$ roundhalves -1.7
-1.5
```

Comment: Thanks, Renaud. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you update this to give a few examples of `how to call this function`... for us noobs out there who know nothing.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy Just like with any bash function: `functionName parameters`. See the update answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
awk '{print int(($1+0.25)/0.5)*0.5}'.
```

PS. If you want to round a number to nearest x (such as 0.1, 50, 100, etc.), just use

```
awk '{print int(($1+x/2)/x)*x}'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unoriginal answer fashioned after a very useful comment left by @CharlesDuffy on the accepted answer. The only difference is that I have removed the here strings so that I can use this function on both sh and bash.

```
roundhalves() {
    printf '%s * 0.5\n' "$(printf '%1.f' "$(printf '%s * 2\n' "$1" | bc)")" | bc
}
```

Just thought it might be of use to anyone trying to write portable scripts.